# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access Denied for 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, mysql-error-1045

I have been having issues with root password.

> sudo mysql -u root -p
>
> Enter password
>
> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access Denied for 'root@localhost' (using pasword: YES)

I have been through this a couple times and can't figure it out. I just set the root password when I setup the mysql server.

Comment: this is a question nobody can answer but yourself. you are doing it right but you are inputting a wrong password. that's all. nobody except for yourself can possibly know why you type in a wrong password...

Comment: I went through the change password process and still getting ERROR

Answer (score 0):

The password for root on mysql is (potentially) different from the root password on the server.

If it's a new setup, have you tried without the -p, to log in without a password.

Comment: Yes, I currently changed the password and still getting ERROR 1045

Answer (score 0):

If using phpMyAdmin make sure that the host of that user is set to localhost.

Just by inspecting the root user accounts, it can be seen that there is more than one root user with different host values. So if your user with the localhost option doesn't work create another user with the same name and give it a host  127.0.0.1 value

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on mysql 15.1 on Amazon Linux 2:

Try entering the password on the same line (without a prompt):

$mysql -u root -p<password>

Remember "no space" between "-p" and "pasword"

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem,,Check all your Ini files in your configs. I cant remember which one though.